# How to place draggable object in a center of a target object

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

I have one `UIView` which is a target and one `UIImage` which is a draggable object. The task is to place `UIImage` inside `UIView` if it's touching it.

Here is my code:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first, let target = dropTarget {
            let position = touch.location(in: self.superview)
            let isOnTarget = target.frame.contains(position)

            if isOnTarget {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue:"onTarget")))
                // Make it stay there
                let targetHeight = target.frame.size.height
                let targetWidth = target.frame.size.width
                self.center = CGPoint(x: targetHeight, y: targetWidth)
            } else {
                self.center = originalPosition
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that `UIImage` attaches at the bottom left corner, outside `UIView` and it should be in a center of it.

How can I make it stay in the middle of target if it's touching it?

Comment: If UIView and UIImageView have common superview: self.center = target.center

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.center = CGPoint(x: targetHeight/2, y: targetWidth/2)
```

Comment: I tried that at first attempt and this is not working. I get image displaced outside UIView.